# Why does Python not read the next line (if)?

Tags: python, if-statement

I wrote the program about Pythagorean I got my answer but python doesn't read (break) after (if) .
My program title : (Special Pythagorean triplet),
there is a one answer exist for `((a+b+c=1000)&(a**2 + b**2 =c**2) )` I want find a*b*c .
I know `(a=200, b=375, c=425)` but when program starts it never stop and it continue.
It also types the product of these three numbers.

```
import random as r
def pyth(b,d,c):
    pyth = None
    if b**2+c**2 == d**2 :
        pyth = True
        h=d*c*b
        print(h)
        return pyth
    if b**2+d**2==c**2 :
        pyth= True
        h=d*c*b
        print(h)
        return pyth
    if d**2 + c**2 == b**2:
        pyth =True
        h=d*c*b
        print(h) 
        return pyth
   else:
       pyth = False 
       return 

a = list(range (150,1000))
b=0
c=0
d=0
h = 0
for i  in range(0,10000000):
    b = r.choice(a)
    c = r.choice(a)
    d = 1000-b-c
    e = b+c+d
if e == 1000 :
    pyth(b,d,c)
if pyth == True:
    break
else:
    continue
```

Comment: `break` can only be used in a `for` or `while` loop. Your `break` is not in the loop.

Comment: You shouldn't use the same name `pyth` for a variable and a function. The variable is replacing the function.

Comment: Did you copy the indentation correctly? You should be getting an error when `break` and `continue` are outside a loop.

Comment: `if pyth == True` will never succeed. `pyth` is a function, not the value returned by the function.

Comment: @Grismar Why? He wants the loop to stop when the function returns success.

Comment: Hint: You only need to check once if you know that the hypotenuse is the longest side.

Comment: @Barmar I know I once used a language where the return value of a function needed to be assigned to the name of the function.  It's so ancient and obsolete I can't even remember which language it was.  Certainly in Python your advice is fundamental for avoiding confusion and bugs.

Comment: @MarkRansom Sounds vaguely familiar to me, too. I asked https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/17686/what-languages-implements-function-return-value-by-assigning-to-the-function-n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for the `pyth` variable. You can just use `return True` or `return False`.

The `if` statement needs to be indented so it's in the loop.

You need to test the value of the function call.

You don't need `else: continue`. Loops automatically continue unless you break out of them. `continue` is only needed when you want to skip the rest of the loop body and start the next iteration; it's not needed at the end of the body.

```
import random as r

def pyth(b,d,c):
    if b**2+c**2 == d**2 :
        h=d*c*b
        print(h)
        return True
    if b**2+d**2==c**2 :
        h=d*c*b
        print(h)
        return True
    if d**2 + c**2 == b**2:
        h=d*c*b
        print(h) 
        return True
    else:
       return False

a = list(range (150,1000))

for i  in range(0,10000000):
    b = r.choice(a)
    c = r.choice(a)
    d = 1000-b-c
    e = b+c+d
    if e == 1000 and pyth(b,d,c)
        break
```